# Fancybox 3 replace icons by Font Awesome

Tags: fancybox, font-awesome, font-awesome-5, fancybox-3

How can I replace the button icons in fancybox 3 (close, arrow, etc.) by Font Awesome icons?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, to customize icons, simply use `btnTpl` option, like so:

```
  btnTpl: {
    download: '<a download data-fancybox-download class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--download" title="{{DOWNLOAD}}" href="javascript:;">' +
    '<i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>' +
    "</a>",

     // etc..
  }
```

Here is a demo with all icons replaced by Font Awesome - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/YgmBOx

To be honest, free icons look quite ugly, I would suggest to either go pro, choose another icon set or stick with defaults.